# Is it possible to use a Bluetooth earpiece while using a microphone plugged into the headphone Jack?

Tags: 9.0-pie, microphone, samsung-galaxy-note-9, earpiece

I'm going to be attending an event as a representative of a semi-professional podcast.

I will be interviewing several people but, it is a long, busy event with no area for formal interviews, so I will be using my phone (Samsung Galaxy Note 9) with an external microphone to save space.

In discussion with the podcast host it was suggested that we try to set up a "live feed" so that he can give any input during the interview.
The "live feed" isn't too much of an issue as I am capable of streaming content from my phone.

My main concern is being able to hear him over the crowd, usually a Bluetooth earpiece would solve this.
However, I'm not sure if an external microphone plugged into the headphone Jack port would override the earpiece as the microphone.

Does anyone have any experience using both a Bluetooth earpiece and a Jack microphone simultaneously?
If nobody has tried this before, is it even theoretically possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fair amount of testing on my Samsung Galaxy Note 9, using server different apps, I have discovered that it is not possible to use a 3.5mm jack microphone in conjunction with Bluetooth headphones.

Instead I had to use a 3.5mm splitter cable (widely available online) and connect my microphone and regular 3.5mm jack headphones.